# Zend2: Redirect with parameter?

Tags: zend-framework2

I have the following code:

```
$id = $this->getID();
$this->redirect()->toRoute(
    'assign-person-route', 
        array(
            'controller' => 'person',
                'action' =>  'assign-person'
        )
 );
```

How do I pass the "id" along to the controller that i'm about to open so that I can access the ID in the next view. Ideally, I would love to be able to end up at a URL like this:

```
/person/assign-person/1
```

where 1 is the ID. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible in ZF2 by implementing a Router mechanism in zend
[Routing and controllers](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/user-guide/routing-and-controllers.html)

Comment: a big vague, but it pointed me in the right direction and solved my problem. thanks!

Comment: I haven't implemented router is ZF2, so was not sure about it. Anyway glad it helped.